# designing a similarity table

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, machine-learning, information-retrieval

I am unable to think of a better way to solve the following problem...?
Imagine I have a big table where rows and columns are some sort of ids.. lets say book id

```
book_id-->1    2     3     .....
  1       1   0.92    0.33
  2
  3
```

The entry in this table tells you how much similar each book is..
so from above table.. book 1 and book 2 have 0.92 similarity index.

So, I have already calculated this in the bankend.. for lets say "n" entries.

From n+1, data comes real time..

So the first step I have to do is fill this new row.. A very naive approach is this.

```
 i = 0; i < total_books ; i++
    sim(book(n+1),book(i))
```

Lets say the calculation to calculate any books similarity is very fast.
But since this has to happen "n" times, this adds up..

and if there are "m" new books then its an n^2 operation ( i think).
Is there a better algorithm/ data structure that can render this computation acceptable.

Also, just to fill on some background.
This similarity is nothing but dot product between two vectors.
(googling cosine similarity will give an idea). But its nothing fancy.. just taking dot products between two vectors.. and it will return a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: If you want the cartesian square of similarity measures, then I don't see how you can reduce this beyond O(n^2). However, if you have some other objective, such identifying if a new document has similarity > X, then there are some interesting approaches that have begun to appear in the literature. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you add 1 book to a collection of n books, it performs n operations
When you add m books to a collection of n books, it performs (n) + (n+1) + ... (n+m-1) operations which is (to be verified) : n*m + (1+2 + ... (m-1)) so it should be O(n*m + m*m).

If you have implemented your solution in a naive way, you can half the computation time by computing and storing sim(book_i,book_j) only when id(book_i) < id(book_j) (this does not change the complexity).
Then, when you want to retrieve sim(i,j), you just have to make sure that you are using argument in the correct order.

Comment: Umm.. can you elaborate a bit more. Why would I want to do the sim calculation when book_i id < book_j id.. 
I mean, when I am calculating the sim_score for book number 100 of lets say 200,000 books.. 
then I would still compare the sim_score betwen book number 1 and 100, 2 and 100.. and 200,000 and 100? or is it that i misunderstood you? Thanks

Comment: Josay ment that sim() is symmetric, i.e. sim(a,b)==sim(b,a). So you only need to compute sim(a,b) if a < b, otherwise you just look up sim(b,a).